# jQuery Change order of events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Is there a way to change the order in which jQuery events happen? I haven't been able to find a clear answer.

I have an outer and an inner div.  Whenever you click on the inner div, the inner div event fires first. Then the outer div events, even though one was created before and after.

https://jsfiddle.net/nLvaehky/5/

```
$("#outerDiv").on("mousedown", function() {
    alert('outer div clicked!');
});

$("#innerDiv").on("mousedown", function() {
    alert('inner div clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/nLvaehky/9/)**.

You need to stop the event from bubbling to the parent div using `stopPropagation()` :

```js
$("#outerDiv").on("mousedown", function() {
  alert('outer div clicked!');
});


$("#innerDiv").on("mousedown", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  alert('inner div clicked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerDiv" style="background-color:blue;">
  <br /><br /><br /><br />
  <br /><br /><br /><br />
  <div id="innerDiv" style="background-color:green;">
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
  </div>
  <br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Ha! Beat me to it. :)

Comment: Thanks this makes sense.  I was thinking of it the wrong way.  If I want the inner to fire and not the outer, I use stopPropagation like you said.  If I want the outer to fire and not the inner, then there is no point to even assign the inner.

Comment: Glad I could help brother, that happens all the time to all of us

Answer (score 1):

The order of the execution depends on how you put them in your js file (top to bottom, left to right). But in this case it triggers the `innerDiv` event first because that was the element you clicked. It doesn't matter if you placed the `$("#outerDiv").on("mousedown" ...)` first.

But it executes the the `mousedown` event of the `outerDiv` because the click propagates upwards in the [DOM tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes), so if you want to stop that propagation you can use the `stopPropagation()` event mentioned in "Zakaria Acharki" answer.